# Maintaining order when selecting a static group from a table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I have a list static list of Ids in a particular order:

```
List<int> ordered = new List<int> {7,2,3,4,5};
```

And I would like to select the items out of the database maintaining that order.

The trivial:

```
 var posts = ( from p in Current.DB.Posts
                        where ordered.Contains(p.Id)
                        select p).ToList();
```

Comes back fast, but out of order.

How do I select these posts out of the db and maintain the order in an elegant and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a combination of Marc's answer and your answer:

```
var dict = Current.DB.Posts.Where(p => ordered.Contains(p.Id))
           .ToDictionary(p => p.Id);
return ordered.Select(id => dict[id]).ToList();
```

Since it omits the `OrderBy` step, I suspect that it will be a bit more efficient. It's certainly a bit prettier.

Comment: This is much more concise than my solution. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't explicitly include an order-by clause, you only really have a *set* - any ordering is purely convenience and will *usually* happen to be on the clustered index - but IIRC this is not guaranteed (and I imagine things like the server choosing to use parallelism would throw this out)

Include an order-by; either at the DB, or at the client. Alternatively, throw the results into a dictionary:

```
var dict = Current.DB.Posts.Where(p => ordered.Contains(p.Id))
                  .ToDictionary(p => p.Id);
```

then you can pull out the one you need at will, ignoring order.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up going with:

```
        var reverseIndex = ordered.Select((id, index) => new { Id = id, Index = index }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Id, s => s.Index);

        model.Posts = Current.DB.Posts
            .Where(p => postIds.Contains(p.Id))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(p => reverseIndex[p.Id] )
            .ToList();
```

Ugly, yet reasonably efficient for large lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could project the `List<int>` onto your list of posts.

```
var posts = ( from p in Current.DB.Posts 
                        where ordered.Contains(p.Id) 
                        select p).ToList(); 

return ordered.Select(o => posts.Single(post => post.Id == o)).ToList();
```

You could also do this at the database retrieval level but you'd be doing multiple `select` statements

```
ordered.Select(o => Current.DB.Posts.Single(post => post.Id == o)).ToList();
```

Comment: The trouble here is that i suspect that top one is fairly inefficient

Comment: It's just a single lookup for each of your int values; you are going to have to perform that matching process at some point regardless so I don't think it's a concern.

Comment: .. I mean posts.Single(post => post.Id == o) ... will scan through the materialized list of posts multiple times, imagine you are pulling out 10,000 posts, that would be about 5000*10000 compares looking up stuff in the list.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't think there is a more efficient way that could be considered 'simple'.  You could put the posts into a tuple along with their required position as a second property, and then sort by that property - but you still need to do 'for each post find its position in this list of ints'.  I think that's unavoidable.